# Facebook redirect "via app"

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated facebook to my android app, and posting through the app. 
On below posted messages by my application I see "via 'MyAppName'", clicking on it leads to facebook application site, how can I change this link to my google play for example

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is "via app"?

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope it got more clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link will redirect to your app link that you mentioned in the dashboard. The apps which redirect "via app" to their own site would not be the canvas apps, but the app for their website. You can't just give any link to it.

Comment: So how for example instagram or other apps redirect "via app" to their sites ?

Comment: as I said, they don't have the canvas app, their app url is same as their website url.